# Moodle a.logo css location

Tags: css, location, moodle, graphical-logo

I've just installed Moodle on my server. I can't find a location of css file with logo adjustment! Firebug shows "[server_name]/theme/styles.php/afterburner/[some_number]/all" since afterburner is default template. Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

All themes including the afterburner theme can be found in the /theme directory inside your Moodle root.

The afterburner theme and the style sheet that controls the logo can be found here:

theme/afterburner/style/afterburner_styles.css